# Java in script library called from Lotusscript via LS2J - updated Java requires Notes client restart

Tags: java, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I'm running a small snippet of Java from a script library (see image below) in an `.nsf` that's used to resize images that users attach to documents.

[image: example code location]

The code is called from Lotusscript via LS2J. The Lotusscript code itself is called via a form button with a document in edit mode.

As I'm going along testing this I'm finding that any code changes are not running (i.e. it's running the previous code revision). I've tried:

- Saving the Java in the script library
- Recompiling the Java in the script library
- Recompiling the Lotuscript (obviously not likely to work but worth a shot anyway)
- Cleaning and rebuilding the entire project.

The only thing that seems to forces the current code to run is when I restart the Notes client. Although the database in on the server, I'm assuming that the code itself runs on the Notes client.

Is there a way to force the Notes client to use the latest code changes without a Notes client restart?

I'm running HCL Notes client / Domino Designer 12.0.2. The server is 12.0.1FP1.

Comment: Did you try to fully close and then reopen the database in the Notes client?

Comment: I did. I've got in the habit of that when developing Lotusscript which sometimes needs to clear the cache

Comment: Make sure you also close the application in the designer (not only the Notes Client). Sometimes the cache is not cleared when the database is still open in Domino Designer.

Comment: Is there a workaround as this tedious at best?